# Possible to append html before and after template?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to append html before and after a [JQuery.tmpl](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/)?

I would like to insert a nested table in

```
<table id="accTable">
  <tr class="row" id="12345">
  </tr>
  <!-- New row to be inserted here -->
</table>
```

so I have done

```
var dat = [];
$.each(result, function(key, value){
    dat.push({
    FROM: this.date,
    ID: key,
    });
});

var markup = "<tr> <td>${ID}</td> <td>${FROM}</td> </tr>";

$.template("actTemplate", markup);

$('#'+id).tmpl("actTemplate", dat).after('#'+id);
```

But somehow I need to append `<tr><td><table>` and prepend `</table></td></tr>`.

I have thought about adding that HTML to the existing, but it should happen in a button press, so until it is pressed would it look wrong. So I guess the append and prepend have to happen when the template is inserted...?

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

**Update**

In this jsFiffle will a row be added/removed when "Details" is clicked. This is the row that I would like to replace.

http://jsfiddle.net/littlesandra88/hhMM6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it this way:

```
EDITED

var wrapper = $( '<tr id="details"><td><table></table></td></tr>' );
var wrapperTable = wrapper.find( 'table' );
$.tmpl ("actTemplate", dat ).appendTo( wrapperTable  );

wrapper.insertAfter( '#'+id );
```

Comment: When I try that it appends the current row inside the current. It looks strange. I have now added a JSfiddle to the question. Can you see what's wrong?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CoolEsh/hhMM6/1/ - here is the solution if I understand your task correctly. UPDATED one more time: to handle couple details sections: http://jsfiddle.net/CoolEsh/hhMM6/2/

Comment: Yes exactly =) What does `var wrapperTable = wrapper.find( 'table' );` actually do? Which table is it you search for?

Comment: wrapperTable creates markup for what you need: table nested in <tr><td>. Next I use jQuery to actually find this table in created markup (to avoid using ID or CLASS for that table), and then append all data throught template to that table. At the end I wrap all created DOM after given id

Comment: @CoolEsh : Can I ask a bonus question? =) I actually need to give the new table an ID because I need to style it. Can I reuse that ID instead of the `.find()`? I have tried: `var wrapper = $('<tr id="details_' + id + '"><td><table id="actTable"></table></td></tr>'); var wrapperTable = wrapper.('#actTable');` but then I get an XML error...

Comment: You can't do that because currently there are possible to open couple "Details", and then each wrapped table would have same ID property. Use class instead. Also you still need to use find(), because when you searching in wrapper for table this code is not appended to DOM at this moment, that's why you get an error. So use var wrapper = $('<tr id="details_' + id + '"><td><table class="wrapped_table"></table></td></tr>'); and var wrapperTable = wrapper.find( 'table.wrapped_table' ); after that line

Answer (score 2):

I would solve it this way:

```
//create your wrapping elements
var wrapping_elements = $('<tr><td><table class="new-table"/></td></tr>');
$('#'+id).after(wrapping_elements);

//insert your table data
var template_data = $('#'+id).tmpl("actTemplate", dat);
$('table.new-table').append(template_data);
```

Comment: I can't get it to work. I don't get any errors either. I have now added a jsFiffle with my actual code. Can you get it to work with your solution?

Comment: i've updated the code above, seemed I wrongly implemented the after() function